# Simulate click on "Choose" button in QFileDialog object

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I'd like to simulate click on "Choose" button  for automatic testing purpose, but unfortunately I have no idea how to achieve that. Operation system is Ubuntu 16.04. I'd be grateful for code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your button-handler from wherever you want to test it from.

Comment: Why? If you have implemented the handler, surely you csn call it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for help JanneK. That was stupid question... But solution for my was QFileDialogObject->QDialog::accept();

Comment: The more stupid the question, the easier it is to answer. :)